# How can I use something like the onAfterPublish() hook on a versioned dataobject in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I have a simple versioned dataobject in SilverStripe. I'm trying to hook into the publication action and send out an email whenever the dataobject is published.

I don't think the `onAfterPublish()` method is available on dataobjects (only pages), so I'm looking to either mimic that or get enough logic working in the `onAfterWrite()` function.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
static $has_written = false; // Hack so it only fires once on write()
public function onAfterWrite()
{
    parent::onAfterWrite();
    if (!self::$has_written) {
        $stage = $this->getSourceQueryParam("Versioned.stage");
        if ($stage === 'Live') {
            $email = new Email();
            ...
            $email->send();
        }
    }
    self::$has_written = true;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Silverstripe Blocks module. [Block](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks/blob/master/code/dataobjects/Block.php) is Versioned dataobject.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I don't see a hook in there for after publish?

Comment: What version of SS do you use? Who is publishing your dataobject and what method/extension is used? You can implement your own extension that provides doPublish() method like it is implemented on SiteTree.

Comment: The site is running 3.3.1. Any content manager can publish that particular dataobject. Doesn't the doPublish() method just take a dataobject from staged to published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Versioned` class, that is used for versioning `DataObjects`, does not have an `onAfterPublish` hook but it does have an [`onBeforeVersionedPublish` hook](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/source-class-Versioned.html#919) that could be used to send out emails:

```
public function onBeforeVersionedPublish($fromStage, $toStage, $createNewVersion = false) {
    $email = Email::create();
    // ...
    $email->send();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this hook to work. I thought it may be because I'm using my versioned DO in a model admin, but it doesn't work on a page either.

Comment: I believe `onBeforeVersionedPublish` needs to be applied through a DataExtension to your DataObject, and not declared straight in your custom DataObject itself. Have you tried this function through a DataExtension?